# How to extract data from an html table where cells have different types?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two problems to solve.  I am trying to create an editable table which the user enters data into.  Two of the columns are number input and one column is a select value.  The fourth column is action buttons for new,edit,delete.  I have searched everywhere for some kind of tutorial on how to do this but found nothing useful.  The table row is created in javascript when the user clicks on Add New.  They then click on a green add icon to accept the data.
In my javascript I have written a little function called displayTableData() which I call when the user clicks the 'add' button.  This was just to verify that I could extract the data and display it in an alert.  But nothing happens.  Furthermore, using cell.innerHTML doesn't work on a 'select' value.

The second problem is that after the user clicks on 'add' and the data is accepted, if they then click on the 'edit' button the 'select' drop down is lost.

You can try this out in my code snippet. I notice when I run this I am getting an uncaught error but don't understand why. I am new to javascript. I would have expected millions of people to have done something like this but I couldn't find an entire example that worked.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
// Append table with add row form on add new button click
$(".add-new-your-super-contribution").click(function(){
  $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
  var index = $("table tbody tr:last-child").index();
      var row = '<tr>' +
          '<td label="Age" class="center"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="age" id="age"></td>' +

          '<td label="Contribution" class="align-right"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="contribution" id="contribution"></td>' +
                  
          '<td label="Taxation">' +
            '<select id="your-super-contribution">' +
              '<option id="your-before-tax-super-contribution">Before</option>' +
             '<option id="your-after-tax-super-contribution">After</option>' +
            '</select>' +
          '</td>' +
   
          '<td label="Actions" class="center"><a class="add-your-super-contribution" title="Add" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE03B;</i></a>' +
    '<a class="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE254;</i></a>' +
     '<a class="delete" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE872;</i></a></td>' +
      '</tr>';
    $("table").append(row);     
  $("table tbody tr").eq(index + 1).find(".add-your-super-contribution, .edit").toggle();
      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  });

    // Add row on add button click
    $(document).on("click", ".add-your-super-contribution", function(){
        var empty = false;
        var input = $(this).parents("tr").find('input[type="text"]');
        input.each(function(){
            if(!$(this).val()){
                $(this).addClass("error");
                empty = true;
            } else{
          $(this).removeClass("error");
      }
        });
        $(this).parents("tr").find(".error").first().focus();
        if(!empty){
            input.each(function(){
                $(this).parent("td").html($(this).val());
            }); 
            $(this).parents("tr").find(".add-your-super-contribution, .edit").toggle();
            $(".add-new-your-super-contribution").removeAttr("disabled");
      displayTableData();
        }       
    });


    // Edit row on edit button click
    $(document).on("click", ".edit", function(){        
        $(this).parents("tr").find("td:not(:last-child)").each(function(){
            $(this).html('<input type="text" class="form-control" value="' + $(this).text() + '">');
        });     
        $(this).parents("tr").find(".add-your-super-contribution, .edit").toggle();
        $(".add-new-your-super-contribution").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });


    // Delete row on delete button click
    $(document).on("click", ".delete", function(){
        $(this).tooltip('hide');

      //  $(this).off();
      $(this).parents("tr").remove();
      $(".add-new-your-super-contribution").removeAttr("disabled");
  });
});

function deleteAllYourSuperContribution() {
  $("#your-super-contributions-table > tbody").empty();
}

function displayTableData() {
  var tableBody = document.getElementById("your-super-contribution-table").getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

  var values = [];

  for (var r = 0, n = tableBody.rows.length; r < n; r++) {
    for (var c = 0, m = tableBody.rows[r].cells.length; c < m; c++) {
      cell = tableBody.rows[r].cells[c];
      values[r][c] = cell.innerHTML;
      alert("values " + r + " " + c + " " + values[r][c]);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
/***************************************************************************/
/*                    TABLES                                               */
/**************************************************************************/
table th {
  color: #22769D !important;
  font-weight: bold;
}

table {
  color: #444;
  background-color: #FFF;
  font-size: 70%;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}
.align-right {
  text-align: right;
}

.table-title-border {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #22769D !important;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

table.table input {
  font-size: 95%;
}

.form-button {
  border: 1px solid #FE6D73;
  background-color: #FEF9EF !important;
  color: #22769D;
  font-size: 80%;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}



.table-wrapper {
  background-color: #FEF9EF !important;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;    
}
.table-title {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}
.table-title h2 {
  margin: 6px 0 0;
  font-size: 22px;
}
.table-title .add-new .delete-all {
  float: right;
  height: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-shadow: none;
  min-width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  line-height: 13px;
}

table.table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
table.table tr th, table.table tr td {
  border-color: #e9e9e9;
}
table.table tr td {
  padding: 3px;
}

table.table th i {
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
table.table th:last-child {
  width: 100px;
}
table.table td a {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
  min-width: 24px;
}    
table.table td a.add-your-super-contribution {
  color: #27C46B;
}
table.table td a.edit {
  color: #FFC107;
}
table.table td a.delete {
  color: #E34724;
}
table.table td i {
  font-size: 19px;
}
table.table td a.add-your-super-contribution i {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-right: -1px;
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
}    
table.table .form-control {
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
table.table .form-control.error {
  border-color: #f50000;
}
table.table td .add-your-super-contribution {
  display: none;
}


/****************************** NAVIGATION MEDIQ QUERY  690 px ******************/
@media (max-width: 43.125em) {

  .table-wrapper {
    width: 96%;
  }

  .table-dropdown .nav-link {
    height: 20px;
  }

  table.table tr td {
    padding: 1px;
  }


}

/***************************************************************************************/
/* Phones from up to 319 px                                                            */
/***************************************************************************************/
@media only screen and (max-width: 19.938em) {

  .table-dropdown .nav-link {
    height: 20px;
  }

}

/****************************************************************************************/
/* Phones from 320px up to 479px                                                        */
/*****************************************************************************************/
@media only screen and (min-width: 20em) {


}

/****************************************************************************************/
/* Phones from 480px up to 599px                                                        */
/*****************************************************************************************/
@media only screen and (min-width: 30em) {
  .table-dropdown .nav-link {
    height: 25px;
  }
}


/****************************************************************************************/
/* landscape tablets from 768px up to 991px                                              */
/*****************************************************************************************/
@media only screen and (min-width: 48em) {

  .table-dropdown .nav-link {
    height: 30px;
  }
}

/****************************************************************************************/
/* Large devices from 992px to 1199px                                                    */
/*****************************************************************************************/
@media only screen and (min-width: 62em) {
 

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Varela+Round|Open+Sans">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container-lg">

    <div class="table-wrapper">
        <div class="table-title">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8"><h2>Extra Lump Sum Contributions</h2></div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <button type="button" class="form-button btn-info add-new-your-super-contribution"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add New</button>
                    <button type="button" class="form-button btn-info delete-all-your-super-contributions" onClick="deleteAllYourSuperContribution()"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i> Delete All</button>
                </div>
            </div>  <!---- end row -->
        </div> <!-- end table-title -->

  <table class="table table-bordered" id="your-super-contribution-table">

    <colgroup>
      <col span="1" style="width: 17%;">
      <col span="1" style="width: 28%;">
      <col span="1" style="width: 28%;">
      <col span="1" style="width: 27%;">
    </colegroup>

    <thead class="table-light">
        <tr>
            <th class="center">Age</th>
            <th class="center">Contribution</th>
            <th class="center">Taxation</th>
            <th class="center">Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
  </div>


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of issues

The error was a comma in the selector so that was simple

I had to rewrite several parts of the code. Please study what I did.

One important thing was to move the ID of the table to the tbody and cache it

Another thing was to not have duplicate IDs

If you do NOT disable the add after first click you will need to rewrite the converting the text fields and select to values

Alternatively use contenteditable

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const $table = $("#your-super-contribution-table");
  
const deleteAllYourSuperContribution = () => { $table.empty(); };
const displayTableData = () => {
  const values = $table.find("tr").map(function() { 
    return $("td[data-label]",this).map(function() { 
      return { [this.dataset.label] : this.dataset.label === "Taxation" ? this.querySelector("select").value : this.textContent.trim() }
    }).get()
  }).get()
  console.log(values)
};  
  
  const row = `<tr>
  <td data-label="Age" class="center"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="age" ></td> '
  <td data-label="Contribution" class="align-right"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="contribution"></td>
  <td data-label="Taxation">
    <select class="your-super-contribution-tax">
      <option id="your-before-tax-super-contribution">Before</option>
      <option id="your-after-tax-super-contribution">After</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td label="Actions" class="center"><a class="add-your-super-contribution" title="Add" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE03B;</i></a>
    <a class="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE254;</i></a><a class="delete" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE872;</i></a></td>
</tr>`;

  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  // Append table with add row form on add new button click
  $(".add-new-your-super-contribution").click(function() {
    $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    var index = $("table tbody tr:last-child").index();
    $table.append(row);
    $table.find("tr").eq(index + 1).find(".add-your-super-contribution, .edit").toggle();
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  });

  // Add row on add button click
  $(document).on("click", ".add-your-super-contribution", function() {
    var empty = false;
    var input = $(this).parents("tr").find('input[type="text"]');
    input.each(function() {
      if (!$(this).val()) {
        $(this).addClass("error");
        empty = true;
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass("error");
      }
    });
    $(this).parents("tr").find(".error").first().focus();
    if (!empty) {
      input.each(function() {
        $(this).parent("td").html($(this).val());
      });
      $(this).parents("tr").find(".add-your-super-contribution, .edit").toggle();
      $(".add-new-your-super-contribution").removeAttr("disabled");
      displayTableData();
    }
  });


  // Edit row on edit button click
  $(document).on("click", ".edit", function() {
    $(this).parents("tr").find("td:not(:last-child)").each(function() {
      $(this).html('<input type="text" class="form-control" value="' + $(this).text() + '">');
    });
    $(this).parents("tr").find(".add-your-super-contribution .edit").toggle();
    $(".add-new-your-super-contribution").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  });


  // Delete row on delete button click
  $(document).on("click", ".delete", function() {
    $(this).tooltip('hide');

    //  $(this).off();
    $(this).parents("tr").remove();
    $(".add-new-your-super-contribution").removeAttr("disabled");
  });
});
```

```css
/***************************************************************************/


/*                    TABLES                                               */


/**************************************************************************/

table th {
  color: #22769D !important;
  font-weight: bold;
}

table {
  color: #444;
  background-color: #FFF;
  font-size: 70%;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.align-right {
  text-align: right;
}

.table-title-border {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #22769D !important;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

table.table input {
  font-size: 95%;
}

.form-button {
  border: 1px solid #FE6D73;
  background-color: #FEF9EF !important;
  color: #22769D;
  font-size: 80%;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.table-wrapper {
  background-color: #FEF9EF !important;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
}

.table-title {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}

.table-title h2 {
  margin: 6px 0 0;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.table-title .add-new .delete-all {
  float: right;
  height: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-shadow: none;
  min-width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  line-height: 13px;
}

table.table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table.table tr th,
table.table tr td {
  border-color: #e9e9e9;
}

table.table tr td {
  padding: 3px;
}

table.table th i {
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

table.table th:last-child {
  width: 100px;
}

table.table td a {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
  min-width: 24px;
}

table.table td a.add-your-super-contribution {
  color: #27C46B;
}

table.table td a.edit {
  color: #FFC107;
}

table.table td a.delete {
  color: #E34724;
}

table.table td i {
  font-size: 19px;
}

table.table td a.add-your-super-contribution i {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-right: -1px;
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
}

table.table .form-control {
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

table.table .form-control.error {
  border-color: #f50000;
}

table.table td .add-your-super-contribution {
  display: none;
}


/****************************** NAVIGATION MEDIQ QUERY  690 px ******************/

@media (max-width: 43.125em) {
  .table-wrapper {
    width: 96%;
  }
  .table-dropdown .nav-link {
    height: 20px;
  }
  table.table tr td {
    padding: 1px;
  }
}


/***************************************************************************************/


/* Phones from up to 319 px                                                            */


/***************************************************************************************/

@media only screen and (max-width: 19.938em) {
  .table-dropdown .nav-link {
    height: 20px;
  }
}


/****************************************************************************************/


/* Phones from 320px up to 479px                                                        */


/*****************************************************************************************/

@media only screen and (min-width: 20em) {}


/****************************************************************************************/


/* Phones from 480px up to 599px                                                        */


/*****************************************************************************************/

@media only screen and (min-width: 30em) {
  .table-dropdown .nav-link {
    height: 25px;
  }
}


/****************************************************************************************/


/* landscape tablets from 768px up to 991px                                              */


/*****************************************************************************************/

@media only screen and (min-width: 48em) {
  .table-dropdown .nav-link {
    height: 30px;
  }
}


/****************************************************************************************/


/* Large devices from 992px to 1199px                                                    */


/*****************************************************************************************/

@media only screen and (min-width: 62em) {}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Varela+Round|Open+Sans">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-lg">

    <div class="table-wrapper">
      <div class="table-title">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <h2>Extra Lump Sum Contributions</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <button type="button" class="form-button btn-info add-new-your-super-contribution"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add New</button>
            <button type="button" class="form-button btn-info delete-all-your-super-contributions" onClick="deleteAllYourSuperContribution()"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i> Delete All</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!---- end row -->
      </div>
      <!-- end table-title -->

      <table class="table table-bordered">

        <colgroup>
          <col span="1" style="width: 17%;">
          <col span="1" style="width: 28%;">
          <col span="1" style="width: 28%;">
          <col span="1" style="width: 27%;">
          </colgroup>

          <thead class="table-light">
            <tr>
              <th class="center">Age</th>
              <th class="center">Contribution</th>
              <th class="center">Taxation</th>
              <th class="center">Actions</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="your-super-contribution-table">

          </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your help is most appreciated.  I will look closely at this tomorrow as it is now evening in Western Australia.  Our Queen is dead and our Parliament has been cancelled.  It's a big day in Australia.

Comment: Thank you for your time helping with this.  I see you have made some good changes.  Taking all the code for the row out of the function certainly makes things neater.  I see how you have determined when to check for the selector based on the label, otherwise just get the textContent.  Thanks a lot.  It's easy to learn when someone shows you how.

Answer (score -1):

i made some changes in your function, now the error is gone however i am not sure about functionality. see if it's working as per expectation.

```
function displayTableData() {
  var tableBody = document.getElementById("your-super-contribution-table").getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

  var values = [];

  for (var r = 0, n = tableBody.rows.length; r < n; r++) {
    for (var c = 0, m = tableBody.rows[r].cells.length; c < m; c++) {
      cell = tableBody.rows[r].cells[c];
      values[r] = values[r]||[]
      values[r][c] = cell.innerHTML;
      alert("values " + r + " " + c + " " + values[r][c]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: sure.. from the looks of it, answer from @mplungjan solves all of your issue!